# Animate GMapPlot w/ Python/Bokeh

Tags: python, google-maps, animation, coordinates, bokeh

I'm a very nooby programmer and this is my first Stack Overflow question.  :)

So I'm trying to animate a car's trip on google maps using Python. I used matplotlib at first and could get a dot animated over the path line... then I tried using bokeh and successfully got the path to overlay on google maps...

My problem is that I haven't found a good way to do both (animate plot over google maps).

My data is in the form of Lat/Long coordinates.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's my code that does the gmapplot... I'd rather have this and no animation than animation with no GMAP. My goal is to animate that "car" dot.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, vform
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from bokeh.models import (GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, Line, Circle,
    DataRange1d, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool, HoverTool)

data = np.genfromtxt('Desktop\Temp Data for Python\test data 3.csv', delimiter=',',
    names=True)

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=np.average(data['Latitude']),
    lng=np.average(data['Longitude']), map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)

plot = GMapPlot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), map_options=map_options,
    title="My Drive")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=data['Latitude'], lon=data['Longitude'],
    speed=data['GpsSpeed'],))

path = Line(x="lon", y="lat", line_width = 2, line_color='blue')
car = Circle(x=data['Longitude'][0], y=data['Latitude'][0], size=5, fill_color='red')

plot.add_glyph(source, path)
plot.add_glyph(source, car)
plot.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool(),
    HoverTool(tooltips=[("Speed", "@speed"),]))

output_file("gmap_plot.html")
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could have a slider widget that controls the position of your car dot. The slider example found in the bokeh docs (or github repository, I can't remember) helped me when I started using sliders.

Just so you are aware, I was having problems with latlng points showing up in the correct locations. There is about a 10px offset. This is an open issue (github issue 2964).

The following code currently is just producing a generic bokeh Figure, but in theory, if you change it from a `Figure` to a `GMapPlot` it *should* work.  I wasn't able to get this working with GMapPlots directly. I think this may be because of github issue 3737. I can't even run the Austin example from the bokeh docs.

Hopefully this is what you had in mind

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, ColumnDataSource, show, vplot
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models import (Slider, CustomJS, GMapPlot, 
                          GMapOptions, DataRange1d, Circle, Line)
import numpy as np

output_file("path.html")

# Create path around roundabout
r = 0.000192

x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,100)*r
x2 = np.linspace(1,-1,100)*r
x = np.hstack((x1,x2))

f = lambda x : np.sqrt(r**2 - x**2)

y1 = f(x1)
y2 = -f(x2)
y = np.hstack((y1,y2))

init_x = 40.233688
init_y = -111.646784

lon = init_x + x 
lat = init_y + y

# Initialize data sources.
location = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[lon[0]], y=[lat[0]]))
path = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=lon, y=lat))

# Initialize figure, path, and point
"""I haven't been able to verify that the GMapPlot code below works, but 
this should be the right thing to do. The zoom may be totally wrong, 
but my latlng points should be a path around a roundabout.
"""
##options = GMapOptions(lat=40.233681, lon=-111.646595, map_type="roadmap", zoom=15)
##fig = GMapPlot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), map_options=options)

fig = Figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=600)

c = Circle(x='x', y='y', size=10)
p = Line(x='x', y='y')

fig.add_glyph(location, c)
fig.add_glyph(path, p)

# Slider callback
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(location=location, path=path), code="""
    var loc = location.get('data');
    var p = path.get('data');

    t = cb_obj.get('value');

    /* set the point location to the path location that
       corresponds to the slider position */
    loc['x'][0] = p['x'][t];
    loc['y'][0] = p['y'][t];

    location.trigger('change');
""")

# The way I have written this, 'start' has to be 0 and 
#  'end' has to be the length of the array of path points.
slider = Slider(start=0, end=200, step=1, callback=callback)

show(vplot(fig, slider))
```

Comment: Do you mind putting together some example code? Recently I have had success using things like slider tools and such in bokeh, however, that's because the bokeh plot objects have a data source attribute that I update on callback, and I can't figure out how to do something similar with the GMapPlot lines, like bokeh lines vs GMapPlot lines are slightly different objects with different attributes, if that makes sense.